Why is the following exercise is an improvement on a Lemma?
The following is taken from the text An Introduction to Grobner Bases by: Ralf Froberg
Background
Lemma  65: Let $\mathfrak{a}$ be an ideal and let $\mathfrak{p_i}$ be prime ideals for $i=1,\ldots,s$. if $\mathfrak{a}\subset\cup_{i=1}^{s}\mathfrak{p_i}$, then $\mathfrak{a_1}\subset \mathfrak{p_i}$ for some $i$.

Proof.   We use induction over $s$.  If $s=2$ and $\mathfrak{a}\subseteq\mathfrak{p_1}\cup\mathfrak{p_2},\mathfrak{a}\nsubseteq\mathfrak{p_1},\mathfrak{a}\nsubseteq\mathfrak{p_2}$ there exists $a_1\in\mathfrak{a}\setminus\mathfrak{p_1},a_2\in\mathfrak{a}\setminus\mathfrak{p_2}$.  Then $a_1+a_1\in \mathfrak{a}$ but $a_1+a_2\not\in \mathfrak{p_1}$ because $a_1\not\in \mathfrak{p_1}$ and $a_2\in \mathfrak{p_1}$.  In the same way we see that $a_1+a_2\not\in \mathfrak{p_2}$, which gives a contradiction. (Note how in this part we haven't used that $\mathfrak{p_i}$ are prime ideals, only that they are ideals.)  Now suppose that $s>2$ and that $\mathfrak{a}\cap\mathfrak{p_i}\nsubseteq\cup_{j\neq i}\mathfrak{p_j}$ for all $i$ (so all ${\mathfrak{p}_i}'s$ are really needed).  Take for each $i$ an $a_i\in\mathfrak{a}\cap\mathfrak{p_i}\setminus\cup_{j\neq i}\mathfrak{p}_j.$ Then we get that $a=a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_s\in \mathfrak{a}$.  We have $a_2\cdots a_s\not\in \mathfrak{a_1}$ (here we use that $\mathfrak{p}_1$ is a prime ideal) so $a\not\in \mathfrak{p}_1$ since $a_1\in \mathfrak{p}_1$.  If $i>1$ then $a_1\not\in \mathfrak{p}_i$ and $a_2\cdots a_s\in \mathfrak{p}_i$, so $a\not\in \mathfrak{p}_i$ which gives us a contradiction.

Exercsie 4:  Show the following improvement of Lemma 65.  Let $\mathfrak{a}\subset \cup_{i=1}^{s}\mathfrak{a_i}$.  If all but at most two of the $\mathfrak{a_i}'s$ are prime ideals, then $\mathfrak{a}\subset \mathfrak{a_i}$ for some $i$.
Questions
I would like to know how and in what sense Exercise 4 above is an improvement of Lemma 65 with the condition: If all but at most two of the $\mathfrak{a_i}'s$ are prime ideals...

Same dumb typos as in your previous post, which tells me you did a copy and paste and did not bother to see the corrections made there. "$a_1+a_2+,\ldots,a_s$"  is wrong. $\mathfrak{a}_1$ is wrong.

@ArturoMagidin thank you for pointing it out.  I forgot to also make the same corrections here for this post.

@ArturoMagidin I will post a screenshots of the theorem in the other post.  This way, there will not be any misunderstandings.

This question is another example  making it clear that you have not mastered the prerequites for a commutative algebra course.

Your question is about logic - not algebra - so I have removed the algebra tags.

The lemma requires all of the $\frak a_i$ to be prime, but the improvement allows up to two of them not to be prime, right? So the improvement relaxes the hypotheses but draws the same conclusion.

so when one can shown the same result of a theorem by relaxing its hypothesis, then it is usually term an "improvement".  Basically, weaker hypothesis is always better?

Same return for a smaller investment. I'd say that's an improvement.
